# Parsing multiple json arrays in a json object

Tags: android, json

I have a json object being returned that has multiple arrays within the json object. I am able to parse a json object if it has one array in it (with  `jObject.getJSONArray("2013-10-30")`), but not multiple. The amount of arrays (i.e. the dates) would be changing almost everyday (some days there wouldn't be any) and that is where I get stuck. I'm not sure how to get a list of all the array names and then iterator through that.

```
{
"2013-10-30": [
    {
        "id": "399",
        "Time": "00:50:46"
    }
],
"2013-10-29": [
    {
        "id": "398",
        "Time": "21:44:09"
    },
    {
        "id": "393",
        "Time": "10:53:01"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Use`jObject.keys()` to obtain an `Iterator` of the string names (in your case the dates). See the `keys()` method of the `JSONObject` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `iterate` over the keys and get the `JSONArray` for each key as follow:

```
Iterator<String> keys = jObject.keys();
while(keys.hasNext()){
    String key = keys.next();
    try{
         JSONArray array = jObject.getJSONArray(key);
         // do something with the array
         // ...
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```